# How do I change left with element label?

Tags: jquery

My code like this:

```
<label><li><input name="skills[]" class="skills" value="1" type="checkbox" /></li>a</label>
<label><li><input name="skills[]" class="skills" value="2" type="checkbox" /></li>b</label>
```

For change (left element) of checked  checkbox, I use this code:

```
$('input.skills').on('change', function() {
if($(this).is(':checked'))
{
    $(this).parents('li').append('<span class="text">add</span>');
} else {
    $(this).parents('li').find('.text').remove();   
}


$(this).animate({left:'500'},1000);
  });
```

However don't change LABEL location, just change checked check box location.

Comment: which label? are you referring to the `span`?

Comment: First of all, you are animating the `input`, not the `label` (which is a `span` and not a `label`). Secondly, add `50px` behind `500` in your animate : `$(this).animate({left:'500px'},1000);`

Comment: Elements need to have `position: relative;` in onder to animate left, right, etc.

Comment: `li` and `input` within `label`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can move the entire li. http://jsfiddle.net/pyuAU/

HTML

```
<ul class="skill-holder">
    <li><input name="skills[]" class="skills" value="1" type="checkbox" /></li>
<li><input name="skills[]" class="skills" value="2" type="checkbox" /></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.skill-holder > li {
    position: relative;
}
```

JS

```
$('.skill-holder').on('change', '.skills', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        parent = $this.closest("li"),
        moved;
if(moved = $this.is(':checked'))
{
    parent.append('<span class="text">اضافه</span>');
} else {
    parent.find('.text').remove();   
}


    parent.animate({left:moved ? 500: 0},1000);
  });
```